# supsample from list of data frames entries with "character"

Tags: r, dataframe

I got a list that contains 9 data frames and each data frame contains the following lines:

```
ENSEMBL SYMBOL  DESCRIPTION GO_ID   GO_NAME baseMean    log2FoldChange  lfcSE   stat    pvalue  padj
ENSG00000176076 KCNE5   potassium voltage-gated channel subfamily E regulatory subunit 5 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6241] GO:0016020;GO:0006811;GO:0005249;GO:0008016;GO:0060307;GO:0016021;GO:0005886;GO:0005515;GO:0005251;GO:1902282;GO:0015459;GO:0044325;GO:0086005;GO:0086011;GO:0086091;GO:0097623;GO:0098915;GO:1902260;GO:0060048;GO:0060306;GO:0008076;GO:1901381;GO:0060372;GO:0086008;GO:1901379;GO:0086014;GO:1901380;GO:1903765;GO:2001257;GO:0086013   membrane;ion transport;voltage-gated potassium channel activity;regulation of heart contraction;regulation of ventricular cardiac muscle cell membrane repolarization;integral component of membrane;plasma membrane;protein binding;delayed rectifier potassium channel activity;voltage-gated potassium channel activity involved in ventricular cardiac muscle cell action potential repolarization;potassium channel regulator activity;ion channel binding;ventricular cardiac muscle cell action potential;membrane repolarization during action potential;regulation of heart rate by cardiac conduction;potassium ion export across plasma membrane;membrane repolarization during ventricular cardiac muscle cell action potential;negative regulation of delayed rectifier potassium channel activity;cardiac muscle contraction;regulation of membrane repolarization;voltage-gated potassium channel complex;positive regulation of potassium ion transmembrane transport;regulation of atrial cardiac muscle cell membrane repolarization;voltage-gated potassium channel activity involved in cardiac muscle cell action potential repolarization;regulation of potassium ion transmembrane transport;atrial cardiac muscle cell action potential;negative regulation of potassium ion transmembrane transport;negative regulation of potassium ion export across plasma membrane;regulation of cation channel activity;membrane repolarization during cardiac muscle cell action potential   36.1939021451241    0.002641963898243   0.476944728069481   2.37060878769676E-05    0.999981085278488   0.999981085278488
```

First line are the names.

Based on a character key from column "GO_NAME", for example "membrane", I would like to extract the corresponding lines from a data frame in the list.

When I do:

```r
resfold.sort.up <- res.tables[[7]][which(res.tables[[7]]$log2FoldChange >= 1 &
                                               res.tables[[7]]$padj < 0.05),]
```

I get a supsampled dataframe with only the values that correspond to the conditions:

```
summary(resfold.sort.up)
   ENSEMBL             SYMBOL          DESCRIPTION           GO_ID             GO_NAME         
 Length:779         Length:779         Length:779         Length:779         Length:779        
 Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character   Class :character  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Mode  :character  
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
                                                                                               
    baseMean         **log2FoldChange**      lfcSE             stat            pvalue               **padj**          
 Min.   :     3.20   **Min.   :1.002**   Min.   :0.1242   Min.   : 2.603   Min.   :0.000e+00   Min.   :0.0000000  
 1st Qu.:    30.79   1st Qu.:1.274   1st Qu.:0.3286   1st Qu.: 3.126   1st Qu.:4.219e-06   1st Qu.:0.0001551  
 Median :   145.11   Median :1.599   Median :0.4307   Median : 3.758   Median :1.712e-04   Median :0.0025233  
 Mean   :  3934.57   Mean   :1.708   Mean   :0.4478   Mean   : 4.032   Mean   :1.356e-03   Mean   :0.0095110  
 3rd Qu.:  1149.65   3rd Qu.:2.034   3rd Qu.:0.5480   3rd Qu.: 4.600   3rd Qu.:1.772e-03   3rd Qu.:0.0148887  
 Max.   :232975.04   Max.   :4.846   Max.   :0.9520   Max.   :11.358   Max.   :9.241e-03   Max.   **:0.0499960**
```

But it does not work when I do:

```r
zinc <- res.tables[[7]][which(res.tables[[7]]$GO_NAME == "membrane"),]
zinc <- res.tables[[7]][which(res.tables[[7]]]$GO_NAME %in% "membrane"),]
```

It outputs empty data frame.

Also the following does not work:

```r
zinc <- res.tables[[7]] %>% filter(GO_NAME == "membrane")
```

dput output of the object:

```r
structure(list(ENSEMBL = c("ENSG00000002549", "ENSG00000003400", 
"ENSG00000003402", "ENSG00000004660", "ENSG00000004700", "ENSG00000004975", 
"ENSG00000006062", "ENSG00000008294", "ENSG00000010030", "ENSG00000010244"
), SYMBOL = c("LAP3", "CASP10", "CFLAR", "CAMKK1", "RECQL", "DVL2", 
"MAP3K14", "SPAG9", "ETV7", "ZNF207"), DESCRIPTION = c("leucine aminopeptidase 3 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:18449]", 
"caspase 10 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1500]", "CASP8 and FADD like apoptosis regulator [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1876]", 
"calcium/calmodulin dependent protein kinase kinase 1 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:1469]", 
"RecQ like helicase [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:9948]", "dishevelled segment polarity protein 2 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:3086]", 
"mitogen-activated protein kinase kinase kinase 14 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:6853]", 
"sperm associated antigen 9 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:14524]", 
"ETS variant transcription factor 7 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:18160]", 
"zinc finger protein 207 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:12998]"
), GO_ID = c("GO:0030145;GO:0005737;GO:0006508;GO:0008235;GO:0004177;GO:0019538;GO:0005634;GO:0046872;GO:0005654;GO:0005829;GO:0008233;GO:0016787;GO:0005925;GO:0005515;GO:0030496;GO:0070062;GO:0005802", 
"GO:0005515;GO:0042981;GO:0006508;GO:0008234;GO:0004197;GO:0097199;GO:0008233;GO:0016787;GO:0006915;GO:0005737;GO:0097194;GO:0097190;GO:0005829;GO:0031625;GO:0043123;GO:0007166;GO:0006919;GO:0097153;GO:0097200;GO:0097342;GO:0031265;GO:0035877", 
"GO:0005515;GO:0042981;GO:0006508;GO:0008234;GO:0004197;GO:0005737;GO:0006915;GO:0016032;GO:0002020;GO:0005123;GO:0016504;GO:0044877;GO:0001666;GO:0007519;GO:0009617;GO:0010667;GO:0010976;GO:0014732;GO:0014842;GO:0014866;GO:0032869;GO:0033574;GO:0042060;GO:0043066;GO:0043154;GO:0043403;GO:0051092;GO:0060546;GO:0070374;GO:0071364;GO:0071392;GO:0071456;GO:0071549;GO:0071732;GO:0072126;GO:1901740;GO:1903055;GO:1903427;GO:1903845;GO:1903944;GO:1904036;GO:2000347;GO:2001237;GO:0031264;GO:0031265;GO:0045121;GO:0097194;GO:0097190;GO:0005829;GO:0043123;GO:1902041;GO:1902042;GO:0006919;GO:0008047;GO:0097153;GO:0097199;GO:0097200;GO:0060544;GO:0097342", 
"GO:0005524;GO:0006468;GO:0004672;GO:0000166;GO:0005634;GO:0005737;GO:0004674;GO:0016301;GO:0016740;GO:0016310;GO:0005515;GO:0005516;GO:0035556;GO:0004683;GO:0005654;GO:0005829;GO:0045860", 
"GO:0005524;GO:0003676;GO:0005634;GO:0016020;GO:0000166;GO:0005654;GO:0016787;GO:0003677;GO:0005515;GO:0004386;GO:0032508;GO:0003678;GO:0006310;GO:0005737;GO:0006281;GO:0000724;GO:0009378;GO:0036310;GO:0043138;GO:0000733;GO:0006268;GO:0005694", 
"GO:0005515;GO:0035556;GO:0016055;GO:0051091;GO:0045944;GO:0005737;GO:0001934;GO:0003151;GO:0043507;GO:0005634;GO:0016020;GO:0005654;GO:0005886;GO:0005829;GO:0031410;GO:0007275;GO:0016235;GO:0016604;GO:0042802;GO:0060071;GO:0090090;GO:0006355;GO:0060070;GO:0061024;GO:0005109;GO:0035567;GO:0090179;GO:0150012;GO:1904886;GO:0019901;GO:0019904;GO:0030674;GO:0043621;GO:0048365;GO:0001843;GO:0003007;GO:0007379;GO:0007507;GO:0022007;GO:0034613;GO:0035282;GO:0035329;GO:0043547;GO:0044340;GO:0060029;GO:0061098;GO:0090103;GO:0016328;GO:0030136;GO:0045177;GO:0045334", 
"GO:0005524;GO:0006468;GO:0004674;GO:0004672;GO:0005737;GO:0043231;GO:0000166;GO:0016301;GO:0016740;GO:0016310;GO:0005654;GO:0005829;GO:0001650;GO:0000165;GO:0005515;GO:0051607;GO:0006955;GO:0004709;GO:0000186;GO:0043123;GO:0033209;GO:0038061;GO:0071260;GO:0007249;GO:0004704", 
"GO:0005515;GO:0005078;GO:0005737;GO:0016020;GO:0005829;GO:0005765;GO:0031410;GO:0005764;GO:0048471;GO:0034451;GO:0001669;GO:0016192;GO:0070062;GO:0030335;GO:0019894;GO:0007257;GO:0008432;GO:0030159;GO:0042802;GO:0000187;GO:0032418;GO:0042147;GO:0043410;GO:0045666;GO:0051146;GO:0051149;GO:0016021", 
"GO:0006355;GO:0042025;GO:0003700;GO:0043565;GO:0005634;GO:0005654;GO:0003677;GO:0005515;GO:0006357;GO:0000981;GO:0000790;GO:0030154;GO:0001227;GO:1990837;GO:0000122;GO:0006366;GO:0000977;GO:0009887", 
"GO:0003676;GO:0005634;GO:0003723;GO:0005737;GO:0046872;GO:0007049;GO:0005654;GO:0005730;GO:0005856;GO:0008270;GO:0003677;GO:0003700;GO:0051301;GO:0005694;GO:0005874;GO:0000776;GO:0007059;GO:0000775;GO:0005819;GO:0000777;GO:0008017;GO:0005515;GO:0050821;GO:0001578;GO:0006355;GO:0090307;GO:0008608;GO:0007094;GO:0008201;GO:0000070;GO:0046785;GO:0051983;GO:1990047"
), GO_NAME = c("manganese ion binding;cytoplasm;proteolysis;metalloexopeptidase activity;aminopeptidase activity;protein metabolic process;nucleus;metal ion binding;nucleoplasm;cytosol;peptidase activity;hydrolase activity;focal adhesion;protein binding;midbody;extracellular exosome;trans-Golgi network", 
"protein binding;regulation of apoptotic process;proteolysis;cysteine-type peptidase activity;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic signaling pathway;peptidase activity;hydrolase activity;apoptotic process;cytoplasm;execution phase of apoptosis;apoptotic signaling pathway;cytosol;ubiquitin protein ligase binding;positive regulation of I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling;cell surface receptor signaling pathway;activation of cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in execution phase of apoptosis;ripoptosome;CD95 death-inducing signaling complex;death effector domain binding", 
"protein binding;regulation of apoptotic process;proteolysis;cysteine-type peptidase activity;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity;cytoplasm;apoptotic process;viral process;protease binding;death receptor binding;peptidase activator activity;protein-containing complex binding;response to hypoxia;skeletal muscle tissue development;response to bacterium;negative regulation of cardiac muscle cell apoptotic process;positive regulation of neuron projection development;skeletal muscle atrophy;regulation of skeletal muscle satellite cell proliferation;skeletal myofibril assembly;cellular response to insulin stimulus;response to testosterone;wound healing;negative regulation of apoptotic process;negative regulation of cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process;skeletal muscle tissue regeneration;positive regulation of NF-kappaB transcription factor activity;negative regulation of necroptotic process;positive regulation of ERK1 and ERK2 cascade;cellular response to epidermal growth factor stimulus;cellular response to estradiol stimulus;cellular response to hypoxia;cellular response to dexamethasone stimulus;cellular response to nitric oxide;positive regulation of glomerular mesangial cell proliferation;negative regulation of myoblast fusion;positive regulation of extracellular matrix organization;negative regulation of reactive oxygen species biosynthetic process;negative regulation of cellular response to transforming growth factor beta stimulus;negative regulation of hepatocyte apoptotic process;negative regulation of epithelial cell apoptotic process;positive regulation of hepatocyte proliferation;negative regulation of extrinsic apoptotic signaling pathway;death-inducing signaling complex;CD95 death-inducing signaling complex;membrane raft;execution phase of apoptosis;apoptotic signaling pathway;cytosol;positive regulation of I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling;regulation of extrinsic apoptotic signaling pathway via death domain receptors;negative regulation of extrinsic apoptotic signaling pathway via death domain receptors;activation of cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process;enzyme activator activity;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic process;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in apoptotic signaling pathway;cysteine-type endopeptidase activity involved in execution phase of apoptosis;regulation of necroptotic process;ripoptosome", 
"ATP binding;protein phosphorylation;protein kinase activity;nucleotide binding;nucleus;cytoplasm;protein serine/threonine kinase activity;kinase activity;transferase activity;phosphorylation;protein binding;calmodulin binding;intracellular signal transduction;calmodulin-dependent protein kinase activity;nucleoplasm;cytosol;positive regulation of protein kinase activity", 
"ATP binding;nucleic acid binding;nucleus;membrane;nucleotide binding;nucleoplasm;hydrolase activity;DNA binding;protein binding;helicase activity;DNA duplex unwinding;DNA helicase activity;DNA recombination;cytoplasm;DNA repair;double-strand break repair via homologous recombination;four-way junction helicase activity;annealing helicase activity;3'-5' DNA helicase activity;DNA strand renaturation;DNA unwinding involved in DNA replication;chromosome", 
"protein binding;intracellular signal transduction;Wnt signaling pathway;positive regulation of DNA-binding transcription factor activity;positive regulation of transcription by RNA polymerase II;cytoplasm;positive regulation of protein phosphorylation;outflow tract morphogenesis;positive regulation of JUN kinase activity;nucleus;membrane;nucleoplasm;plasma membrane;cytosol;cytoplasmic vesicle;multicellular organism development;aggresome;nuclear body;identical protein binding;Wnt signaling pathway, planar cell polarity pathway;negative regulation of canonical Wnt signaling pathway;regulation of transcription, DNA-templated;canonical Wnt signaling pathway;membrane organization;frizzled binding;non-canonical Wnt signaling pathway;planar cell polarity pathway involved in neural tube closure;positive regulation of neuron projection arborization;beta-catenin destruction complex disassembly;protein kinase binding;protein domain specific binding;protein-macromolecule adaptor activity;protein self-association;Rac GTPase binding;neural tube closure;heart morphogenesis;segment specification;heart development;convergent extension involved in neural plate elongation;cellular protein localization;segmentation;hippo signaling;positive regulation of GTPase activity;canonical Wnt signaling pathway involved in regulation of cell proliferation;convergent extension involved in organogenesis;positive regulation of protein tyrosine kinase activity;cochlea morphogenesis;lateral plasma membrane;clathrin-coated vesicle;apical part of cell;clathrin-coated endocytic vesicle", 
"ATP binding;protein phosphorylation;protein serine/threonine kinase activity;protein kinase activity;cytoplasm;intracellular membrane-bounded organelle;nucleotide binding;kinase activity;transferase activity;phosphorylation;nucleoplasm;cytosol;fibrillar center;MAPK cascade;protein binding;defense response to virus;immune response;MAP kinase kinase kinase activity;activation of MAPKK activity;positive regulation of I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling;tumor necrosis factor-mediated signaling pathway;NIK/NF-kappaB signaling;cellular response to mechanical stimulus;I-kappaB kinase/NF-kappaB signaling;NF-kappaB-inducing kinase activity", 
"protein binding;MAP-kinase scaffold activity;cytoplasm;membrane;cytosol;lysosomal membrane;cytoplasmic vesicle;lysosome;perinuclear region of cytoplasm;centriolar satellite;acrosomal vesicle;vesicle-mediated transport;extracellular exosome;positive regulation of cell migration;kinesin binding;activation of JUN kinase activity;JUN kinase binding;receptor signaling complex adaptor activity;identical protein binding;activation of MAPK activity;lysosome localization;retrograde transport, endosome to Golgi;positive regulation of MAPK cascade;positive regulation of neuron differentiation;striated muscle cell differentiation;positive regulation of muscle cell differentiation;integral component of membrane", 
"regulation of transcription, DNA-templated;host cell nucleus;DNA-binding transcription factor activity;sequence-specific DNA binding;nucleus;nucleoplasm;DNA binding;protein binding;regulation of transcription by RNA polymerase II;DNA-binding transcription factor activity, RNA polymerase II-specific;nuclear chromatin;cell differentiation;DNA-binding transcription repressor activity, RNA polymerase II-specific;sequence-specific double-stranded DNA binding;negative regulation of transcription by RNA polymerase II;transcription by RNA polymerase II;RNA polymerase II regulatory region sequence-specific DNA binding;animal organ morphogenesis", 
"nucleic acid binding;nucleus;RNA binding;cytoplasm;metal ion binding;cell cycle;nucleoplasm;nucleolus;cytoskeleton;zinc ion binding;DNA binding;DNA-binding transcription factor activity;cell division;chromosome;microtubule;kinetochore;chromosome segregation;chromosome, centromeric region;spindle;condensed chromosome kinetochore;microtubule binding;protein binding;protein stabilization;microtubule bundle formation;regulation of transcription, DNA-templated;mitotic spindle assembly;attachment of spindle microtubules to kinetochore;mitotic spindle assembly checkpoint;heparin binding;mitotic sister chromatid segregation;microtubule polymerization;regulation of chromosome segregation;spindle matrix"
), baseMean = c(23376.8787157806, 2713.79225899981, 42238.1259582663, 
1433.91720047543, 5206.00196432318, 925.859889853068, 1750.28185455516, 
33411.5909356096, 956.737632085951, 10076.7692899315), log2FoldChange = c(0.271707652763339, 
-0.681426948086774, -0.0163799606838739, -0.0204695561755436, 
-0.0137616247671651, -0.0357564297678292, 0.476496746229374, 
0.468725893869883, 0.394652308380454, -0.0429381387495938), lfcSE = c(0.124625571463051, 
0.128753056542653, 0.15622381214385, 0.22145415312069, 0.073434309551688, 
0.0914892763439141, 0.131321153102949, 0.158708845707789, 0.564293078273227, 
0.0619884080943365), stat = c(2.18024217065847, -5.29261514316052, 
-0.104867967131229, -0.0923663634893925, -0.187426126067159, 
-0.390737474927452, 3.62834445922282, 2.95351148557167, 0.768682447494629, 
-0.692696050935598), pvalue = c(0.0292395151910413, 1.20579501774098e-07, 
0.916480577306441, 0.926406963199414, 0.851326539907845, 0.695991295598479, 
0.000285244518736332, 0.0031418091692241, 0.44208184736964, 0.488500317895496
), padj = c(0.113143463875383, 9.80217069154537e-06, 0.963492165764715, 
0.968728132499139, 0.930338366383467, 0.840225634251198, 0.00374400014825083, 
0.0226343174065838, 0.658871858552358, 0.698648017652697)), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: are you a 100% sure there is an entry in the column GO_NAME spelled  "membrane"? without any trailing white spaces or different spellings?

Comment: Instead of copy/paste of lines, please post the `dput` of `res.tables[[7]]`. The `structure` output allows us to read in your object on our end. Use `head` and `tail` for sample if data is too large: `dput(head(res.tables[[7]], 10))`.

Comment: @Parfait the requested information has been posted. Please let me know if you need anything else. Did not know about the dput command. this is perfect to post reproducible objects!

Comment: Because `GO_NAME` is actually a very long character column with semicolon delimited values. You need to search *within* the column since `membrane` will not exist as sole value in column. Therefore, consider `grep`: `zinc <- res.tables[[7]][grep("membrane", res.tables[[7]]$GO_NAME),]`

Comment: @Parfait, did not know that grep worked inside R! this one worked, but may I ask if I want to search only for
A: "manganese ion binding"
OR
B: ";membrane;" should I also add the ";" in the grep search?

Comment: Yes, `grep` will search any character pattern and even run regex for instance if you need both patterns: `grep("manganese ion binding|;membrane;", res.tables[[7]]$GO_NAME)`. See demo: https://rextester.com/HALOTQ21794. Fortunately, semicolon is not a regex operator like pipe, `|`. Otherwise you would need to escape with backslashes: `\\|`.

Comment: @Parfait would you mind write a proper answer, not commed (with the escaping of special characters) to mark it as solved? thnak you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented, your earlier search returns an empty data frame since the searched term is part of the larger strings in the character column, `GO_NAME`. Therefore, instead of `==` or`%in%` operators which expects *whole* word matches, consider `grep` to search string patterns *within* larger string:

```
zinc <- res.tables[[7]][grep("membrane", res.tables[[7]]$GO_NAME),]
```

As background, `grep` is part of the family of string pattern matching in `base` R:

```
grep(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE)

grepl(pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
      fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

sub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
    fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

gsub(pattern, replacement, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

regexpr(pattern, text, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
        fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

gregexpr(pattern, text, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
         fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)

regexec(pattern, text, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE,
        fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE)
```

Hence, `grep` can run regex for pattern matching where complex searches may require `perl=TRUE`:

**`or`**

```
filter_df <- res.tables[[7]][grep("manganese ion binding|;membrane;", res.tables[[7]]$GO_NAME),]
```

**`and`**

```
res.tables7[grep("(?=.*manganese ion binding)(?=.*membrane)", res.tables7$GO_NAME, perl=TRUE),]
```

**`not`**

```
filter_df <- res.tables7[grep("^(?!.*membrane)", res.tables7$GO_NAME, perl=TRUE),]
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/GNF27377)</kbd>

If searching on regex operators which are usually special characters like `- [] () | $ =` among others, be sure to escape in R with double backslashes to treat operator as literal value (i.e., for pipe: `\\|`).